# such $2p-1,2q-1,2pq-1$ be square numbers, $p,q$ is prime

Tags: number-theory

Let $p,q$ be prime number,and such $2p-1,2q-1,2pq-1$ be square numbers,Find $p,q$

it is easy to find $p=q=5$ then $2p-1,2q-1,2pq-1$ is square,I don't known have other case?

Comment: I wrote a program to check for any more solutions. I can verify that there are no prime pairs under a million that satisfy your equation. Can't prove it analytically

Comment: oh，This is  Russia contests.

Comment: (I meant to say, besides p = 5 and q = 5)

Comment: @abandon: is there a link to the contest so I can read the solution, or the contest is holding now, i.e. no solution available?

Comment: @Alexey,I can't see it ,because is from mathlinks

Answer (score 1):

This is no answer, but maybe someone can use the intermediate result.

Suppose

$$2p-1=a^2$$
$$2q-1=b^2$$
$$2pq-1=c^2$$

Then, $a,b$ and $c$ must be odd. Set $a:=2k+1$ , $b:=2l+1$ , $c:=2m+1$

Then, we have

$$p=2k^2+2k+1=k^2+(k+1)^2$$
$$q=2l^2+2l+1=l^2+(l+1)^2$$
$$pq=2m^2+2m+1=m^2+(m+1)^2$$

So, $p$,$q$ and $pq$ must be the sum of two consecutive perfect squares.